# Do we need relative prime in the definition of a quadratic residue?

Tags: quadratic-residues

From my lectures I know that $a$ is a quadratic residue mod $m$ if there is a $b$ such that $b^2\equiv a \pmod m$.
But in several book I now read that $a$ and $m$ have to be coprime.
That would mean that $4$ is not a quadratic residue $\mod 6$.
But obiously we have $2^2\equiv 4\pmod 6$.
So I wonder why some authors use this definition?

Comment: It might be nice if all authors could agree on basic mathematical definitions, but the fact is that they do not.  We have to live with that.

Comment: [From Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue):   e.g., modulo 15 the product of the nonresidues 3 and 5, or of the nonresidue 5 and the residue 9, or the two residues 9 and 10 are all zero

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate of the question linked to by @RobertIsrael, but I added an answer there that perhaps throws some additional light on the issue.